# Issue connecting to MySql Service from Virtual Machine in Azure China

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-china

I have a Microsoft Azure account in China, in which there is a Virtual Machine and a "mysql database on azure" service set up.

I can RDP onto the VM from my development PC (in the UK) and I can connect to the MySql database from my development PC. However, I cannot connect to the MySql database from the Azure VM.

When attempting to connect using MySql Workbench, I get the following error:

"SSL connection error: socket layer receive error"

I have checked the configuration of the VM and of the MySql server and everything looks correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now resolved this. In case anyone comes across a similar problem, the issue is with the version of MySql Workbench we were using.

Hosted MySql in Azure China works with MySql Workbench 6.2, but does not work with 6.3.

Comment: Installing newest version of MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 enabled me to connect to Azure MySQL without SSL errors (used version 6.3.6 before)

Comment: Same issue with a VM in Azure US - 6.3.6 did not work.